# RESTfull website in php

Tags: php, rest

I am having hard time understanding the RESTfull architecture of website. I do get the basic concept of routing and uri etc. So in order to understand it, i decided to make a basic website in php to get the implementation concept in brains muscles memory.

There are lots of RESTful framework in php and many tutorials around it, but i want to learn the implementation of the concept. Something the framework will do it for me and i will not learn.

Can someone <strike>suggest</strike> give me a kick-starter guide/code to build a REST website in PHP. without using any framework. Instruction to properly route the requests etc. A student learner guide.

**EDIT :**
Apparently the word *suggest* makes people think this question is not a good stack overflow Q/A format. I am asking for help as a student. And `suggest` sounds a more polite word than `give`, the reason i use it.

Comment: I'm non related at all with apigee. But I've found that book really interesting http://pages.apigee.com/web-api-design-ebook.html .
After writing a restfull app is pretty straight forward if you are used to doing apps already... It's actually the principle of REST is that it's easy and logical

Comment: @lonesomeday It Does look like similar question but i have visited every link in every answer in that post and several other post on SO. I am trying to learn implementation of REST. Most of the links in posts gives theoretical overview or guide of some framework. I need some do-it-yourself-and-learn guide.

Comment: @charly It looks like a good book and i will read it. But currently, Before heading over to API building, i want to learn building simple website in RESTfull manner. Instead of getting variables in $_REQUEST array like i generally do. But thanks for the book.

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha That really doesn't fit the StackOverflow Q&A format...

Comment: @lonesomeday It does fit in same way as the link you gave above. I cant understand the REST in a implementable way and so i am asking for help. I am not requesting a framework, recommendation, software etc. A short code in answer explaining the http requests implementation is all what is required. I am also not asking for views or starting a debate, and i already said i did my homework before posting it here.